# Did I calculate this method of moments estimator correctly?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, independence

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKTSV.png)

My Solution:
$$\bar{x}=\int_0^1(\theta+1)x^{\theta+1}dx$$
$$=\frac{\theta+1}{\theta+2}$$
Therefore $\theta=\frac{2\bar{x}-1}{1-\bar{x}}$

Is this the correct way to do this kind of question? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, since you have one paramater, the only moment you want is the mean, and you  have correctly calculated the mean in terms of the paramater and inverted that function to solve for the parameter in terms of the mean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Answer is correct and maybe you want some explanation?

Assume $X_i$ is i.i.d. to $X$,

$$EX = \int x dF(x) = \int_0^1 x f(x; \theta) dx = \frac{\theta+1}{\theta+2}$$

We use the mean $\overline{x}$ as a statistical estimate for $EX$,

$$E\overline{x} = \frac{\sum EX_i}{n} = EX$$

so we solve

$$\overline{x} = \frac{\theta+1}{\theta+2}$$

and get the estimate for $\theta$.